# Flatten a list of lists (statements separated by a comma) into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, split, nested-lists, flatten

I have a list of statements. Each statement has a number of other statements separated by commas.

```
gf = ['citrus fruit,black bread,margarine,ready soups', 'tropical 
fruit,yogurt,coffee, margarine', 'whole milk'] ## it has elements (lists with multiple items separated by EXTERNAL commas).
```

I need to transform it into:

```
gf_n = ['citrus fruit', 'black bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups', 'tropical fruit', 'yogurt', 'coffee', 'margarine','whole milk']
```

The individual elements (words or a group of words) can be repeated. In the future, I will need to calculate the frequency of every element (e.g. "citrus fruit") and the frequency of every two-item combination (e.g. 'black bread' and 'margarine')

Here is my code and the result is not what I need:

```
gf_list = list(gf.split(","))

gf_item = []

gf_item = [item for sublist in gf_list for item in sublist]
```

this is what I get surprisingly (letters - not words)

```
['c', 'i', 't', 'r', 'u', 's', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'u'] # first 10 elements
```

What do I do wrong?

SOLUTION (after some time I came up with this):

```
for subl in lst:

    gf_item.append(subl.split(","))
```

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the language.

Comment: Parse and flatten the list (`gf_n = sum((s.split(',') for s in gf), [])`) and if leading and trailing spaces should _not_ be preserved, you need to trim them (`[s.strip() for s in gf_n]`).

Answer (score 1):

```
 gf_item = [i.strip() for i in gf for i in i.split(',')]
```

Using a generator-

```
def flatten(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        for i in x.split(','):
            yield i.strip()
        return 
    try:
        for i in x:
            yield from flatten(i)
    except TypeError:
        yield x 

gf = ['citrus fruit,black bread,margarine,ready soups', 'tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee, margarine', 'whole milk']
gf_new = list(flatten(gf))

lst = [['alice', 'gun'], ['bob', 'tree', ' mot'],['cara']]
lst_new = list(flatten(lst))

print(gf_new)
print(lst_new)
```

output:

```
['citrus fruit', 'black bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups', 'tropical fruit', 'yogurt', 'coffee', 'margarine', 'whole milk']
['alice', 'gun', 'bob', 'tree', 'mot', 'cara']
```

Comment: This produces something different:  ['alice', 'gun', 'bob', 'tree', 'mot', 'cara'].  I need: [['alice', 'gun'], ['bob', 'tree', ' mot'], ['cara']]. I only changes elements for brevity

Comment: U didn't mention that u may have nested list in your question. See the example u had given contains a flat list of strings.

Comment: I've edited the answer. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
gf1 = str(gf).replace("[",'').replace("]",'').replace("'",'')
gf_n = [x.strip() for x in gf1.split(',')]
```

which returns:

```
['citrus fruit',
 'black bread',
 'margarine',
 'ready soups',
 'tropical fruit',
 'yogurt',
 'coffee',
 'margarine',
 'whole milk']
```